# New Relic Heroku Java Installation Fails

Tags: java, maven, heroku, jetty, newrelic

I just followed the steps at

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic#java-configuration

from step

**Add the New Relic agent as a Maven dependency**

up until step

**Add the New Relic agent as a Scala+SBT/Play 2 dependency**

to install New Relic add on for my web service (Jetty JAX-RS REST).

I customized the newrelic.yml (same folder as pom.xml) with my own app license_key and app name.  However, when logged onto my Heroku app's newrelic page, I just see a bunch of configuration steps.  After clicking on "Connect to my application", it just stalls.  Needless to say, it's been over a couple of hours with my webservice taking traffic.

I have a feeling new relic isn't even running.  I updated the newrelic.yml to have DEBUG logging, but there were no logs from new relic at startup.  Does newrelic.jar expect the newrelic.yml at the root with pom.xml?

Thanks,

Luke

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to add

```
$JAVA_OPTS
```

in

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* service.Main
```